# stopping ajax when it reaches a specific part of the page?

Tags: ajax

is it possible to have the ajax run until it will read something, for example `<!--end-->`, how do i do that?

I want to call a page, and stop reading the page when it gets to the  - i only need to read the content of the HEAD

Comment: That question doesn't make any sense, you should say what you want to do more clearly.

Comment: Not really - do you want to perform a request and then do something with the result? Why can't you get the whole page and cut the stuff you want after?

Comment: some of the pages are very long... and then it will take time to wait for the entire page to load when i only need the head

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have nothing against php, there is a mean to do it.

Instead of calling for your file, call for a php script, which will parse your file until it meats your marker, in your case `<!--end-->`. Let's name it `parser.php`.

```
<?php

//Retrieve your file. It can be any type of plain text file which doesn't need
//to be interpreted, even html.
$lines = file("yourfile.txt");
$i = 0;
while(trim($lines[$i])!=="<!--end-->"){
    echo $lines[$i];
}

?>
```